# ARM64 UMDF Driver Signing

Tags: windows, driver, umdf, windows-arm64

I'm trying my own UMDF2 driver compiled for ARM64. I use a generic exe-signing certificate which is accepted by windows in x64 or x86.

In arm64 the driver fails to install. On invoking devmgmt.msc and trying to install manually, it says that the driver isn't digitally signed.

I'm trying to use `bcdedit /set testsigning off` and it says that this is a secure boot policy that cannot be modified.

Am I obliged now to use a KMDF driver certificate? Why wouldn't arm64 accept my user-mode certificate?

Comment: Kernel-Mode Code Signing Requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-requirements--windows-vista-and-later-

Driver code signing requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/code-signing-reqs

Comment: Its not kernel mode.

Comment: Doh, I skipped over the U in UMDF. It wouldn't surprise me if arm64 signing requirements are more strict, though I can't find any documentation to support this.